# Detect and remove unused classes in external libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an Android project that has uses several large external libraries (.jar files). Since Android has the 65536 methods limit of DEX, I'd like to remove all classes and methods in the external libraries that I haven't used once in my code.

The problem is that the classes I'm using in the external libraries have dependencies of their own. I wish to identify all of the classes in the external libraries that I do not need (are not used by my code and are not dependencies of classes I do need).

Two clarifications:

1. ProGuard and DexGuard are irrelevant since they do not modify external libraries
2. I do not wish to use custom loaders or split my code into multiple dex files. All I wish to do is identify and remove the classes in question.

Comment: I would not advise you actually modifying the libraries themselves, as you will have to repeat that process every time the libraries are updated. "ProGuard and DexGuard are irrelevant since they do not modify external libraries" -- they do, however, strip out unused classes from external libraries as part of building your APK.

Comment: I don't plan on upgrading these libraries in the near future. ProGuard remains irrelevant as it makes it impossible for me to debug the application since debugging with Eclipse doesn't invoke ProGuard

Comment: found a solution? I'm still looking for one. This does show how to reduce the google play services jar, but is not enought for me: https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71

Comment: fyi: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a hint that may help you out or any other person interested in this topic. The largest majority of people coming here are facing the issue of implementing the multidex. 
However the main problem for most people is that they implement all the google play services instead of just the specific required api from the google play services, and just this makes you reach that method limit count.

So remove this import from your gradle dependancies at the app level and add the required ones only